# Use radio buttons instead of Checkbox popup in Jquery Mobile Table

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-checkbox, jquery-mobile-radio, jquery-mobile-table

Well searching for the code or plugin or anything similar to what i need...

SCREENSHOT:-[image]

The screenshot say it all, basically i want to embed radio buttons for column toggle in jquery mobile tables, so that user can get one column which he selects... Same like a radio button functions...

For the table we implement this line in our code:-

```
<table class="ui-responsive" data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle"  data-column-btn-theme="d" data-column-btn-text="Click to select week's day..." data-column-popup-theme="c">
```

Is their a plugin for it or any custom code available? How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/f5eTT/

Only difference to normal toggle table is that your main column must also be your first column.

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
                <h1>Index page</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <table data-role="table" id="table-column-toggle" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive table-stroke">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>                        
                            <th data-priority="1">Movie Title</th>                            
                            <th data-priority="2">Rank</th>
                            <th data-priority="4">Year</th>
                            <th data-priority="3"><abbr title="Rotten Tomato Rating">Rating</abbr></th>
                            <th data-priority="5">Reviews</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_Kane" data-rel="external">Citizen Kane</a></td>                            
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>1941</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>74</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casablanca_(film)" data-rel="external">Casablanca</a></td>                            
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>1942</td>
                            <td>97%</td>
                            <td>64</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Godfather" data-rel="external">The Godfather</a></td>                            
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>1972</td>
                            <td>97%</td>
                            <td>87</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gone_with_the_Wind_(film)" data-rel="external">Gone with the Wind</a></td>                            
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>1939</td>
                            <td>96%</td>
                            <td>87</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_of_Arabia_(film)" data-rel="external">Lawrence of Arabia</a></td>                            
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td>1962</td>
                            <td>94%</td>
                            <td>87</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Strangelove" data-rel="external">Dr. Strangelove Or How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb</a></td>                            
                            <td>6</td>
                            <td>1964</td>
                            <td>92%</td>
                            <td>74</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Graduate" data-rel="external">The Graduate</a></td>                            
                            <td>7</td>
                            <td>1967</td>
                            <td>91%</td>
                            <td>122</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Oz_(1939_film)" data-rel="external">The Wizard of Oz</a></td>                            
                            <td>8</td>
                            <td>1939</td>
                            <td>90%</td>
                            <td>72</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singin%27_in_the_Rain" data-rel="external">Singin' in the Rain</a></td>                            
                            <td>9</td>
                            <td>1952</td>
                            <td>89%</td>
                            <td>85</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="title"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception" data-rel="external">Inception</a></td>                            
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td>2010</td>
                            <td>84%</td>
                            <td>78</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table data-role="table" id="table-test" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive table-stroke">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>                        
                            <th data-priority="1">Movie Title</th>                            
                            <th data-priority="2">Rank</th>
                            <th data-priority="4">Year</th>
                            <th data-priority="3"><abbr title="Rotten Tomato Rating">Rating</abbr></th>
                            <th data-priority="5">Reviews</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_Kane" data-rel="external">Citizen Kane</a></td>                            
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>1941</td>
                            <td>100%</td>
                            <td>74</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casablanca_(film)" data-rel="external">Casablanca</a></td>                            
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>1942</td>
                            <td>97%</td>
                            <td>64</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Godfather" data-rel="external">The Godfather</a></td>                            
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>1972</td>
                            <td>97%</td>
                            <td>87</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gone_with_the_Wind_(film)" data-rel="external">Gone with the Wind</a></td>                            
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>1939</td>
                            <td>96%</td>
                            <td>87</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_of_Arabia_(film)" data-rel="external">Lawrence of Arabia</a></td>                            
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td>1962</td>
                            <td>94%</td>
                            <td>87</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Strangelove" data-rel="external">Dr. Strangelove Or How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb</a></td>                            
                            <td>6</td>
                            <td>1964</td>
                            <td>92%</td>
                            <td>74</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Graduate" data-rel="external">The Graduate</a></td>                            
                            <td>7</td>
                            <td>1967</td>
                            <td>91%</td>
                            <td>122</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Oz_(1939_film)" data-rel="external">The Wizard of Oz</a></td>                            
                            <td>8</td>
                            <td>1939</td>
                            <td>90%</td>
                            <td>72</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singin%27_in_the_Rain" data-rel="external">Singin' in the Rain</a></td>                            
                            <td>9</td>
                            <td>1952</td>
                            <td>89%</td>
                            <td>85</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="title"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception" data-rel="external">Inception</a></td>                            
                            <td>10</td>
                            <td>2010</td>
                            <td>84%</td>
                            <td>78</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>                
            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript :**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '.ui-page', function(){ 
    alterTablePopup('table-column-toggle', 0);
    alterTablePopup('table-alt',0);    
});

function alterTablePopup(tableID, showColumnID) {    
    if($.mobile.activePage.find('#'+tableID).length > 0) {
        // First unsellect everything, we must trigger click event so table look could change  
        cleanTableColumns(showColumnID, tableID);

        $(document).on('popupafteropen', '#' + tableID + '-popup',function(event, ui) {
            var popup = $(this);        

            //Hide old fieldset
            popup.find('fieldset').hide();
            $.mobile.activePage.find('#radio-fieldset').remove();

            $('<fieldset>').attr({'data-role':'controlgroup','id':'radio-fieldset'}).appendTo(popup);
            popup.find('input').each(function(i){            
                (i === showColumnID) ?   $('<input>').attr({'name': tableID+'-radio','id': tableID+'-radio-'+i,'type':'radio','value':'v'+i,'checked':'checked','class':tableID+'-radio'}).appendTo('#radio-fieldset') :  $('<input>').attr({'name':tableID+'-radio','id':tableID+'-radio-'+i,'type':'radio','value':'v'+i}).appendTo('#' + tableID + '-popup #radio-fieldset');           

                $('<label>').attr({'for':tableID+'-radio-'+i}).text($(this).prev().find('.ui-btn-text').text()).appendTo('#' + tableID + '-popup #radio-fieldset'); 
            }); 
            $('[type="radio"]').checkboxradio();
            $.mobile.activePage.trigger('create');
        }); 

        $(document).on('popupafterclose', '#' + tableID + '-popup',function(event, ui) {
            var popup = $(this);  

            $.mobile.activePage.find('#radio-fieldset').remove();
            popup.find('fieldset').show();        
        });

        $(document).on('vmouseup', '#' + tableID + '-popup #radio-fieldset .ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-radio', function(e){ 
            if(e.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
            {        
                var selectedRadio = $(this).find('[type="radio"]').attr('id').replace(tableID+"-radio-","");
                cleanTableColumns(selectedRadio, tableID);
                e.handled = true;
            }    
        });     
    }
} 

function cleanTableColumns(columnNo, tableID){
    $('#' + tableID + '-popup').find('.ui-checkbox label').each(function(i){
        ($(this).hasClass('ui-checkbox-on')) ? $(this).trigger('vclick') : ''; // Unselect every selected field
        (i == columnNo) ? $(this).trigger('vclick') : ''; // select first for further use       
    });  
}
```

Comment: such a professional answer, thanks a lot... but its not working properly, i think when you click second time the popup does'nt appear... and what if their are more than one tables in a page...?

Comment: You really need to have patience :) Example is fixed, you can even create a plugin out of it.

Comment: hehe, have you looked at new example?

Comment: Can you mail me your table and I will fix it.

Comment: it is a simple time table, the popup i have used have monday, tuesday and so on... i have applied your code only nothing else...

Comment: Still I cant fix it unless I can see your table, my example was made upon official jQM table example. I never tested it on other tables. Just mail it to: dragan.gaic@gmail.com

Comment: Ok, your table is working inside a desktop browser: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/f5eTT/, in a few hours I will check it/fix it on my iPad (as soon as I come home).

Comment: yes desktop its f9, but i tested it on iOS browser, opera mobile and android... all showing me the disturbed results...

Comment: This code now works on iOS and Android. I will not test this on Mobile Opera because older versions are not supported by jQM.

Comment: Actually fiddle is working on phone as far as i tested, but i have implemented this table in an accordian, when i navigate through pages then open the accordian and click the btn... it shows me same... http://i.imgur.com/q7GTjcL.jpg

Comment: Will it be a problem if you mail me your project or can you just strip it on unnecessary code and send me just a bare example to test? I would like to help you but I can't simulate your error.

Comment: here i have created one, http://jsfiddle.net/f5eTT/27/embedded/result/ just click on button then go back to this page again click on "Go to Table" button, you can see the result...

Comment: Tnx, I will do that as soon as I write you an answer for your other question.

Comment: Found the problem and I know how to fix it

Comment: Code and example are updated. In your second table there are two columns because one of them don't have data-priority attribute. Add it if you also want to have only one visible column.

Comment: yes i think its now working properly, can we set a flexible values in data-proirity as we want here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29898/discussion-between-saurabhlp-and-gajotres)

Comment: What do you count as a flexible value? Currently I am not using its value, only its existence. If it exist that column will be hidden until you want to to be shown.